# iOS- Error in displaying the array values in a table

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiview, nsmutablearray, uilabel

In my app, I have created a mutable array named "array".

```
 array=[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"a",@"b",@"c",@"d",@"e", nil];
```

My tableView contains only one row for multiple section, Each section has a customView which contains only one label.
My custom View name is ContentOfCell

```
ContentOfCell * contentOfCell=[[ContentOfCell alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 50)];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:contentOfCell];
```

I have added the array to the label

```
contentOfCell.label.text=[array objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
```

My problem is that it recognises only the first 4 values in the array and the first 4 values is getting repeated in the sections

I thing something is going wrong here

```
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{ 
return [indexPath row]+50;
}
```

If I change 50 by 100, the error occurs if not the values are inserted correctly

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
NSString * cellIdentifier=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"MyTableView"];
cell=[myTableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
if(cell== nil)
{
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
ContentOfCell * contentOfCell=[[ContentOfCell alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 50)];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:contentOfCell];
   contentOfCell.nameField.text=[arr objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
    cell.contentView.backgroundColor=[UIColor whiteColor];
 }}
```

[image]
[image]
Here the view contains only 3 rows, when I scroll down the array is initiated again, then the values are printed again

Comment: can you show code for tableview methods?

Comment: make sure numberOfSectionsInTableView will be equal to array count

Comment: Ya, In numberOfSection delegate I have given return[array count];

Comment: show your code `cellForRowAtIndexpath`? I think, mistake in `dequeueReusable`

Comment: Show the code for cellForRowAtIndexpath

Comment: I found the error, I will update my it in my question

Comment: what is a error you are facing. describes the error

Comment: Check the question properly

Comment: set the contentOfCell = nil after assigning to content view.

Comment: nothing changes @parvind

Comment: this is cell reusing issue ,try creating separate cell for each row .

Comment: I cant use like that, as the values in the array will be retrieved dynamically, so I cant use seperate cells.

Comment: If I increase the array value then, the exception occurs, the 4th value, the value "d" is printed after every 3 rows

Comment: Why to create several questions regarding 1 problem? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20973522/ios-error-using-array-values-in-tableview-dynamically#20973522

Comment: because I didnt get what I wanted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you are not reusing the cell correctly.

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
   NSString * cellIdentifier=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"MyTableView"];
   cell=[myTableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
   ContentOfCell *contentOfCell;
   //Initialization Part. declare objects here
   if(cell== nil)
   {
      //Creation part. Create your new cell here. Do all UI actions here
      cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
      contentOfCell=[[ContentOfCell alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 50)];
      contentOfCell.tag =100;
      [cell.contentView addSubview:contentOfCell];
      cell.contentView.backgroundColor=[UIColor whiteColor];
   }
   else{
      // Reusable part. Reuse the UI controls here from existing cell
      contentOfCell = (ContentOfCell *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:100];
   }
   //Assign all the data here
   contentOfCell.nameField.text=[arr objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
}
```

This is one of the simple mistake often committed by iOS Rookies. 
Kindly check the Apple developer documentation here to understand how a tableview cell is reused
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/tableview_iphone/TableViewCells/TableViewCells.html

Comment: can U please check this link, I have given comments

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20880074/ios-error-in-parsing-the-data/20880308?noredirect=1#comment31335993_20880308

Comment: I want use the coordinates to plot them on the map from the dictionary get me an answer in that page,

Comment: k, can U tell me wat mistake i did in this table view

Comment: Its simple you haven't reused the cell properly. Reusable concept is somewhat big to explain here thats why i gave you the link of apple doc. Kindly refer that or google for how UItableviewcell works. http://www.mobilesce.com/2011/12/27/the-best-way-to-do-custom-reusable-uitableviewcells/

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44317/discussion-between-chandru-and-iprabu)

Answer (score 2):

I implemented same code as below with grouped table.Everything is fine.Please compare your code with below code.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
arrData=[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"a",@"b",@"c",@"d",@"e",@"f",@"g",@"h",@"i",@"j",@"k", nil];

// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
   return 1;
}
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{ 
   return [arrData count];
}
 - (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
{
   return 50.0;
}
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *aCell=[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"da"];
    if(aCell==Nil)
    {
      aCell=[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"da"];

      ContentOfCell *ContentOfCellObj=[[ContentOfCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,320,50)];
      ContentOfCellObj.tag=101;
      [aCell.contentView addSubview:ContentOfCellObj];
     }
     ContentOfCell *ContentOfCellObj=(ContentOfCell*)[aCell.contentView viewWithTag:101];
     ContentOfCellObj.nameField.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[arrData objectAtIndex:indexPath.section]];

     return aCell;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString * cellIdentifier=@"CellIdentifier";//or your custom name
    UITableViewCell* cell=[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    if(cell== nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
        ContentOfCell * contentOfCell=[[ContentOfCell alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 50)];

        contentOfCell.tag = 101;
        [cell.contentView addSubview:contentOfCell];
        cell.contentView.backgroundColor=[UIColor whiteColor];
     }

     ContentOfCell * contentOfCell = (ContentOfCell*)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:101];

     contentOfCell.nameField.text=[arr objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];

     return cell;
}
```

Comment: No, the same thing happens

Comment: Just have a snap at the image, If I scroll down, the upcoming rows contains values a, then b, then c. Till the number of sections

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you set

```
myTableView.dataSource = self;
```

and these two delegate methods

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
   return [arrData count];
}
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{ 
   return 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code, surely it will **resolve your problem**.

**Step 1**. First declare array as global variable

```
@interface YOUR-CLASS-NAME ()
{
     NSMutableArray *array
}
```

**Step 2**. Now set no of sections you need. This means how many time do you want to repeat the array values in table continuously.

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}
```

**Step 3**. Now set no of rows you need to display from your array. This means no of values from your array need to display

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [array count];
}
```

Comment: if I got the answer, I will validate it