# iOS-error in parsing the data

Tags: ios, iphone, json, invalid-argument

In my app, I am parsing the data using JSON

```
NSString * urlString=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://userRequest?userid=bala@gmail.com&latitude=59.34324&longitude=23.359257"];
NSURL * url=[NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
NSMutableURLRequest * request=[NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
NSError * error;
NSURLResponse * response;
NSData *data=[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];
NSString * outputData=[[NSString alloc]initWithData:data encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
NSLog(@"%@",outputData);

SBJsonParser *jsonParser = [SBJsonParser new];
NSDictionary *jsonData = (NSDictionary *) [jsonParser objectWithString:outputData error:nil];
NSLog(@"%@",jsonData);
NSInteger success = [(NSNumber *) [jsonData objectForKey:@"success"] integerValue];
```

After this code executes, In my log it is printed as

```
({  
latitude = "0.000000000000000";  
longitude = "0.000000000000000";  
username = sunil;  
},  
{  
latitude = "80.000000000000000";  
longitude = "30.000000000000000";  
username = arun;  
})
```

But while running, the app crashes, as

```
'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSArrayM objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x910d8d0'
```

Comment: the above code is just fine, the error is somewhere else in your code. please show us the instantiation of your array and the code where you try to access the data in your array since you are trying to call a method on your `NSMutableArray` which only exists for `NSMutableDictionary`

Comment: oh, sorry, I will update it

Comment: According to my knowledge, in json ':' is used instead of '='.. Let me know if i am wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem is, that `jsonParser objectWithString` returns an array with dictionaries in it not dictionaries itself.

Try the following:

```
NSArray *jsonData = (NSArray *) [jsonParser objectWithString:outputData error:nil];

for(NSDictionary *dict in jsonData) {
    NSLog(@"%@",dict);
}
```

Does that work for you ?

Comment: now my dictionary contains many coordinates, I want to plot them, to google maps, any help

Comment: udpate your question or make a new question with detailed description of your problem and what you have tried until now.

Comment: can u help me in this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20902732/how-to-plot-the-markers-in-google-maps-from-a-dictionay-in-ios

Answer (score 1):

Your reponse is `NSArray` which contains `NSDictionary`. So frst get dictionary from array then access value. Also Your `json` not look like correct.

```
for (NSDictionary *dict in responseArray) {
    double latitude = [dict[@"latitude"]doubleValue];
    double longitude = [dict[@"latitude"] longitude];
    NSString* name = dict[@"username"];
}
```

Comment: now my dictionary contains many coordinates, I want to plot them, to google maps, any help

Comment: I know how to use google maps and plot the points, my doubt is i am not aware of retrieving the values from nsdictionary

Comment: In answer you can see how to retrieving value from `NSDictionary`

Comment: can u help me with this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20902732/how-to-plot-the-markers-in-google-maps-from-a-dictionay-in-ios

Answer (score 1):

**1. First of all you are getting NSArray in JSON**

**JSON Starts with    "(" means NSArray**

**JSON Starts with    "{" means NSDictionary**

Here you are getting NSArray which has collection of NSDictionary,

```
    {
        latitude = "0.000000000000000";
        longitude = "0.000000000000000";
        username = sunil;  
    },...
```

**2."success" key is not present in the JSON..**

- Fix

  ```
  NSArray *jsonData = (NSArray *) [jsonParser objectWithString:outputData error:nil];

  If([jsonData count]>0){

      // Has some data
      // Iterate NSDictionary and get data here
  }
  else{

      // No Data
  }
  ```

Comment: now my dictionary contains many coordinates, I want to plot them, to google maps, any help

Comment: can U please help me with this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20902732/how-to-plot-the-markers-in-google-maps-from-a-dictionay-in-ios

Answer (score 0):

some where you are getting data from nsarray with using some object key. that key is invalid to fetching data from array