# How to plot the markers in google maps from a dictionay in ios?

Tags: ios, google-maps, nsarray, nsdictionary, sbjson

In my app, I have done JSON parsing and I got the coordinates in the form of a dictionary, I want to use the coordinates angd plot it in the map,
I have using this

```
SBJsonParser *jsonParser = [SBJsonParser new];    
NSArray *jsonData = (NSArray *) [jsonParser objectWithString:outputData error:nil];
for(int i=0;i<[jsonData count];i++)
{
    NSDictionary *dict=(NSDictionary *)[jsonData objectAtIndex:i];
    Nslog(@"%@",dict);
    double la=[[dict objectForKey:@"latitude"] doubleValue];
    double lo=[[dict objectForKey:@"longitude"] doubleValue];

    CLLocation * loca=[[CLLocation alloc]initWithLatitude:la longitude:lo];
    CLLocationCoordinate2D coordi=loca.coordinate;

    marker=[GMSMarker markerWithPosition:coordi];
    marker.snippet = @"Hello World";
    marker.animated = YES;
    marker.map = mapView;
}
```

it is printed as

```
[{"driver_id":"Tn1234sunil@gmail.com","username":"sunil","latitude":"0.000000000000000",  
"longitude":"0.000000000000000"},  
{"driver_id":"ma12marii@yahoo.com","username":"mari","latitude":"13.040720500000000",  
"longitude":"80.243139600000000"},     {"driver_id":"45sabala@gmail.com","username":"balaji","latitude":"0.000000000000000",  
"longitude":"0.000000000000000"}
```

Then, In my log, it is getting printed as

```
2014-01-04 10:55:48.121 MyTaxi[608:12e03] latitude : 0.000000
2014-01-04 10:55:48.121 MyTaxi[608:12e03] longitude : 0.000000
2014-01-04 10:55:48.122 MyTaxi[608:12e03] latitude : 13.040721
2014-01-04 10:55:48.122 MyTaxi[608:12e03] longitude : 80.243140
2014-01-04 10:55:48.122 MyTaxi[608:12e03] latitude : 0.000000
2014-01-04 10:55:48.123 MyTaxi[608:12e03] longitude : 0.000000
```

But, this doesnt works properly

```
Does any body have an idea how to plot these points to the google maps
```

Comment: is there anybody to help

Comment: an error in coming -[__NSCFString objectAtIndex:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Comment: the longitude and latitude values are loaded in la and lo, the mistake will be from CLLOcation, please help me

Comment: can you print `jsonData` ?

Comment: ya, it is getting printed, even the the values are stored in la and lo

Comment: i have tell you to print it, not asking is there value or not.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44413/discussion-between-chandru-and-viruss-mca)

Comment: what is there to down vote, I cant get the solution anywhere, so I updated this

Comment: U can give down vote, but cant answer this

Comment: Now I cant ask any question, Y U r givng down vote for me

Answer (score 4):

try this one this might be helpful just create a for loop to your count ,increment it ...

```
NSDictionary *dict=(NSDictionary *)[jsonData objectAtIndex:i];
    double la=[[dict valueForKey:@"latitude"] doubleValue];
    double lo=[[dict valueForKey:@"longitude"] doubleValue];

    NSMutableArray * latArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    NSMutableArray * longArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

    [latArray addObject:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:la]];
    [longArray addObject:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:lo]];

    CLLocation * loca=[[CLLocation alloc]initWithLatitude:[[latArray objectAtIndex:i]doubleValue] longitude:[[longArray objectAtIndex:i]doubleValue]];
    CLLocationCoordinate2D coordi=loca.coordinate;

    GMSMarker *marker= [[GMSMarker alloc] init];
    marker=[GMSMarker markerWithPosition:coordi];
    marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake([[latArray objectAtIndex:i]doubleValue], [[longArray objectAtIndex:i]doubleValue]);
    marker.snippet = @"Hello World";
    marker.animated = YES;
    marker.map = mapView;
```

Comment: showing error :  Passing 'id' to parameter of incompatible type 'CLLocationDegrees' (aka 'double')

Comment: array cant be sent to CLLocation,

Comment: it crashes here   CLLocation * loca=[[CLLocation alloc]initWithLatitude:[latArray objectAtIndex:i]    longitude:[longArray objectAtIndex:i]];

Answer (score 1):

I think , You have to **alloc** Marker in for loop,
right now you are creating only one marker,

```
for(int i=0;i<[jsonData count];i++)
{
  NSDictionary *dict=(NSDictionary *)[jsonData objectAtIndex:i];
double la=[dict valueForKey:@"latitude" doubleValue];
double lo=[dict valueForKey:@"longitude" doubleValue];

CLLocation * loca=[[CLLocation alloc]initWithLatitude:la longitude:lo];
CLLocationCoordinate2D coordi=loca.coordinate;

 GMSMarker *marker= [[GMSMarker alloc] init];
marker=[GMSMarker markerWithPosition:coordi];
    marker.snippet = @"Hello World";
    marker.animated = YES;
    marker.map = mapView;
.....

}
```

Comment: what means not working??? some error or what, give proper explanation so somebody may help you.

Comment: @chandru: have you get it?

Comment: @chandru: check your dictionary lat and long, it shows 000000 it should not be that..

Comment: then, please get me some idea

Comment: It should not be zero,

Comment: wat about other values

Comment: 3.040720500000000",  
"longitude":"80.243139600000000